# What does "argue" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

In a sentence with the structure *A argues that S1 because S2.*,say:

> The theory argues that children are fatter nowadays because they are less active than they used to be.

does A provide supports for the claimed cause S2? Or does it mean that A believes that the cause of S1 is S2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on context.  In this case the conclusion of the argument seems to be that S2 caused S1.  It may be possible, though we don't know from this one sentence, that the theory (or the individual arguing for the theory) provides additional support for this claim.